# Does Eclipse tell what minSdkVersion to use in Android?

Tags: android

does Eclipse tell me for what SDKVERSION my code would not work with?
I set the minSdKversion to 4 - and it seem to work, but I dont know really if all components i am using will work on a 4sdk-device^^ is there any method do know what my really minSdk ist?

Comment: No, **you** tell it. You should use the minSdkVersion corresponding to the minimum API level you want to support. Then add a reference to the support library, if required. And use its objects and methods.

Comment: The LINT tool will automatically add compile errors if you are trying to use newer (not allowed) APIs in your code.

Comment: When you use some methods like `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, it will tell you to set Min Sdk version to some number to work. So, i guess..it will.

Comment: hmm yeah, eclipse does not say anything yet  :S but i dont when i set min to 4, that components could now work like google cloud messaging or whatever..

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you will/might get warnings in other parts of your application like this:

[image]

which says

> Attribute "uiOptions" is only used in API level 14 and higher (current min is 4)

I suggest you take a look at the [Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) site from Google, which

> provides information about the relative number of devices that share a certain characteristic, such as Android version or screen size. This information may help you prioritize efforts for supporting different devices by revealing which devices are active in the Android and Google Play ecosystem.

As you can see, the lowest `minSDK` version is 8.